# Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android SDK (Intellij)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, sdk

If I try and run an android project in Intellij I get the following error

Error: Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android SDK

I have JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_JAVA_HOME set in environment variables and I have tools, platform-tools, jdk/bin and android installation all added to the PATH variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems you install only JRE. What OS you use ?